# get ngrx async data from server

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

how to get asynchronous data from the server?

i want to store data in global store for later update

but I can't understand the logic of osynchronous calls like in redux

with simple data, I was able to figure it out, but getting data from the server is not given to me

I really ask for help

app.components.ts:

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { dataSelector, DATA_LOAD } from './store.sevice/ngrx.store/globalStore.action';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  
  data$ = this.store.select(dataSelector)

  constructor(private store: Store) {

    this.store.dispatch(DATA_LOAD());

  }
```

reducer.reducer.ts:

```
import {ActionReducerMap, MetaReducer} from '@ngrx/store';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import { counterReducer, DATA_KEY } from './globalStore.action';


export interface State {
  [DATA_KEY]: any;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  [DATA_KEY]: counterReducer,
};


export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<State>[] = !environment.production ? [] : [];
```

action.action.ts:

```
import {createAction, createFeatureSelector, createReducer, createSelector, on, props} from '@ngrx/store';

export const DATA_KEY = 'DATA';

export const DATA_LOAD = createAction('[DATA] DATA_LOAD');


export const initialState: any = {
  data: {}
};

export const counterReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(DATA_LOAD, state => ({
    ...state.data,
    ...fetch('https://gutendex.com/books')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => data)
  }))
);

export const featureSelector = createFeatureSelector<any>(DATA_KEY);

export const dataSelector = createSelector(
  featureSelector,
  state => state.data
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reducers are only meant for pure (and synchronous) methods.
Side effects, like an API call, belong in @ngrx/effects.
The usual flow is:

- component dispatch FETCH action
- effect picks FETCH action up, makes the API call, and dispatches a FETCH SUCCESS or FETCH ERROR action
- reducers picks up FETCH SUCCESS and updates states
- selectors are updates and component gets the data

Take a look at the example app of ngrx to have an example.

More links:

- https://ngrx.io/guide/effects
- https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app/src/app

Comment: as shown, I did not understand very well.

Comment: book$: Observable<any> = this.store.select((state:any) => console.log(state.DATA.data));

Comment: tracking a store does not change it. although in the effect I see that the data is received app.effect.ts:       ofType(GET_DATA),
      exhaustMap(() => 
        this.service.DataLoad().pipe(
          map(data => {
            console.log(data)
            return DATA_LOAD(data)
          }),
        )
      )

Comment: what could be the problem?